# How to add new router to the mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have some mod_rewrite config, that redirects all requests to the /index.php router. I want to add new router for some kind of path, in example: request to /path/action should be processed with /custom_engine/index.php file. How to do like this?

My existing .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Get rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite all directory-looking urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

# Try to route missing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.  (jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (path/action/)(.*) engine-v2/index.php [L,NC]

# Get rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
RewriteRule ^(path/action/)(.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite all directory-looking urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

# Try to route missing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```